# Where to find google captcha configuration

Tags: recaptcha, captcha

We're using google captcha v2 on live site which is working fine but couldn't find keys & sites in google recaptcha admin account. Where can I find keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because google account doesn't have admin access. Once admin access assigned, we're able to see all sites. Might be someone also facing this issue so this post should be helpful